# Yii2: How to check if activeRecord Model is Empty

Tags: php, activerecord, model, yii2

I am trying to fetch data from database like this:

```
$model = ProductFiles::findAll(['product_id' => $product_id]);
```

When I check `count($model)`, it returns as `0` if the model is empty and when the same model is rendered to view, it returns `count($model)` as `1`. So, I was wondering if there is any way to check `Yii2` `activeRecord` object, if it is empty or not (I tried `isset` but the same result). any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is happening in your case - it would be good to see the code of the controller's action responsible for passing the `$model` to view.

As for the checking if ActiveRecord has been fetched - usually `empty()` is more than enough.

- Static method `findOne()` returns instance of ActiveRecord or `null` if condition is not met.
- Static method `findAll()` returns array of ActiveRecord instances or empty array if condition is not met.

In both cases `empty()` returns `false` if `$model` has been fetched or `true` otherwise.

Comment: I am trying to do like this `if(($model=Sims::find()->where(['imsi'=>$imsi])->andWhere(['status'=>'Inventory Stored SIM'])
                ->orWhere(['status'=>'SIM Returned'])->all()) !== null)`

But if an `IMSI` is not according to the status then still it's returning true.

Comment: @MrFaisal Because `all()` just like `findAll()` returns array (empty or not) and not `null` in any case.

Comment: empty dont work for me and i dont get null , i use andFilterWhere, how to check my result?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($model instanceof ProductFiles) {}
```

Using `instanceof` you can find if object has record or not.